# Prime number theorem via the explicit formula

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, prime-number-theorem

Can the prime number theorem be obtained from the explicit formula,

$\psi(x)=x-\sum_{\zeta(\rho)=0}\frac{x^\rho}{\rho}+O(1)$?

Here, $\psi(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{p^k<x}\log p$

Comment: It does not follow *solely* from the explicit formula, because the Prime Number Theorem requires the nontrivial zeros $\rho$ to have real part $<1$.  Once you have this, you can prove the PNT without the full explicit formula, which typically comes later in most textbooks.  See Montgomery-Vaughan, Multiplicative Number Theory.

Comment: @Stopple I meant to say that does pnt follow from the explicit formula along with the non vanishing of zeta on the boundary of the critical strip?

Comment: So there's two parts:  $\psi(x)\sim x\Rightarrow$ PNT, which is in almost any book on the subject, and the Explicit Formula $\Rightarrow \psi(x)\sim x$.  This latter requires more than just the real part of each individual $\rho<1$, one would need to understand the contribution of all of them.  And, the series is only conditionally, not absolutely, convergent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding on my comments above, most textbooks will show how the Prime Number Theorem follows from $\psi(x)\sim x$.  This does not require the full strength of the Explicit Formula for $\psi(x)$, and most textbooks will prove the PNT before the Explicit Formula.  One needs more than just the real part of each $\rho$ is $<1$; one needs to understand the contribution of all of them.  The fact that the infinite series is not absolutely convergent complicates matters.

However, one can consider instead
$$\psi_1(x)=\int_0^x\psi(u)\, du=\sum_{n\le x}(x-n)\Lambda(n)$$
This function also has an Explicit Formula
$$\psi_1(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\sum_\rho \frac{x^{\rho+1}}{\rho(\rho+1)}-x\frac{\zeta^\prime}{\zeta}(0)+\frac{\zeta^\prime}{\zeta}(-1)-\frac{1}{2} x \log \left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-\coth ^{-1}(x)$$
and now the sum over $\rho$ *is* absolutely convergent.  This is Theorem 28 in Ingham's "The Distribution of Prime Numbers".  Ingham comments on p.74

> A generalised form of Theorem 28 was the basis of de la Vallee
> Poussin's proof of the Prime Number Theorem...

---

(Updated to address the questions of Steven Clark below)

The explicit formula for $\psi_1(x)$ is not obtained by integrating the explicit formula for $\psi(x)$ term by term; again that's not allowed without absolute convergence.  Instead the approach is via an inverse Mellin transform
$$
I(m)=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C(m)}\frac{x^{s+1}}{s(s+1)}\frac{\zeta^\prime}{\zeta}(s)\, ds,
$$
where $C(m)$ is a large rectangle avoiding the zeros of $\zeta(s)$     The Residue Theorem, standard estimates and letting $m\to \infty$ give the explicit formula.  (see Ingham for details.)

Comment: Just to add some details: by monotonicity of $\psi(t)$, $\psi_1(x)-\psi_1(x-h) = \int_{x-h}^{x}\psi(t)dt\le h\psi(x) \le \int_{x}^{x+h}\psi(t)dt = \psi_1(x+h)-\psi_1(x)$ for any $h>0$. So if one proves $\psi_1(t) = t^2/2 + O(R(t))$ using the formula Stopple cites (and a zero-free region) one gets for free $\psi(x)=x +O(h + h^{-1}\max_{[x-h,x+h]} R(t))$. The most common $R$ is $R(t) = t^2 \exp(-c\sqrt{\log t})$ for which $\psi(x) = x + O(h +h^{-1}x^2 \exp(-c'\sqrt{\log x}))$, now take $h=x\exp(-c''\sqrt{\log x})$ to recover PNT.

Comment: I also think some clarification is needed with respect to $\psi_1(x)=\int\limits_0^x \psi(u)\,du$ in the derivation of the explict formula for $\psi_1(x)$ from the explicit formula $$\psi(x)=x-\underset{T\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{|\Im(\rho)|<T}\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}\right)-\frac{\zeta'(0)}{\zeta(0)}-\frac{1}{2} \log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right).$$.

Comment: The $-\frac{1}{2} \log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ term, which is equivalent to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-2 n}}{2 n}$, is the only term in the explicit formula for $\psi(x)$ for which the indefinite integral $\int f(x)\,dx$ doesn't match the definite integral $\int\limits_0^x f(u)\,du$, and it appears in this case the indefinite integral was used instead of the definite integral in the resulting explicit formula for $\psi_1(x)$.

Comment: But $$\psi_1(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\sum_\rho \frac{x^{\rho+1}}{\rho(\rho+1)}-x\frac{\zeta^\prime}{\zeta}(0)-\frac{1}{2} x \log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-\coth^{-1}(x)$$ seems to evaluate with an offset, whereas $$\psi_1(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\sum_\rho \frac{x^{\rho+1}}{\rho(\rho+1)}-x\frac{\zeta^\prime}{\zeta}(0)+\frac{\zeta^\prime}{\zeta}(-1)-\frac{1}{2} x \log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-\coth^{-1}(x)$$ seems to evaluate more correctly.

Comment: I'm curious about the derivation of the $\frac{\zeta^\prime}{\zeta}(-1)$ term in the explicit formula for $\psi_1(x)$ as the residue of $-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} \frac{x^s}{s}$ at $s=-1$ is zero and therefore has no contribution to the explicit formula for $\psi(x)$.

Comment: @StevenClark See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I see now how the $\frac{\zeta^\prime}{\zeta}(-1)$ term is picked up by the residue of $-\frac{x^{s+1}}{s(s+1)}\frac{\zeta^\prime}{\zeta}(s)$ at $s=-1$.

Comment: Very good. I think that your modification of the von Mangoldt version of R's explicit formula is not as well-known as it should be! :)